# Firefox dictionary, deleting false entries

Tags: firefox, spell-check, dictionary

How do I delete a false entry from the Firefox dictionary?

I have added five false entries to the dictionary by mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit Firefox’s Spelling Dictionary**

If you have used Firefox’s built in dictionary, you will know there is a limitation to it. Firefox allows you to easily add words to dictionary, but lacks a user interface for removing words. This can be a problem since the “Add to dictionary” button is directly under the corrected words, providing easy access for adding misspelled words to the dictionary.

Since I frequently add misspelled words, I had to learn the method for removing these words. To remove misspelled words, first close down Firefox then navigate to your profile folder. The folder’s location varies depending on your operating system:

**Windows XP**

C:\Documents and Settings[User Name]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\

**Windows Vista**

C:\users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\

**Mac OS X**

~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/

**Linux**

~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/

Once in your profile folder, look for a file named **persdict.dat**, and open it with your favorite **text editor**. Inside you’ll find all of your custom defined words, each on their own line. Just delete the words which don’t belong and save. Firefox will no longer incorrectly identify those misspelled words as correct.

[Source](http://cavemonkey50.com/2007/03/edit-firefoxs-spelling-dictionary/)

Comment: From time to time I need to re-read this answer :P  Too bad I can't upvote it each time.

Answer (score 3):

From the always useful [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/244497/remove-misspelled-words-from-your-firefox-dictionary):

> 1. Open your application data folder. On XP or Vista, go to your Start menu
>      and hit Run (or just press Windows-R)
>      and paste in
>      %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles; on
>      your Mac, navigate to
>      ~/Library/Application
>      Support/Firefox/Profiles.
> 2. Find your profile folder, which by default should look something like
>      xxxxxxxx.default.
> 3. Inside your profile folder, find the file called persdict.dat and open
>      it up in your text editor of choice.
> 4. Now just find the misspelling, delete
>      it, and you're done.

Comment: This still works in Firefox version 44.0.2 (2016-02-12) - though the profile folder does not necessarily end in ".default"; a sample name is "yynxpuma.default-1439568940109".

Answer (score 0):

See ["Firefox Dictionary & Spell Checker Hacks: Edit Misspelled Words, Merge with Word Dictionary"](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/11/firefox-2-spelling-dictionary-hacks.html). Basically, you need to manually edit the file named persdict.dat.