# can I remove words from the firefox dictionary?

Tags: windows, firefox

Where is the firefox dictionary? I would like to remove 2 words from mine.

For the curious, I'd like to remove the words its and it's so that I can eyeball them and make sure I'm using the correct one.

Firefox Quantum, 67.0

Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox dictionary, deleting false entries](https://superuser.com/questions/40158/firefox-dictionary-deleting-false-entries)

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1087366

While it is (relatively) simple to edit the custom dictionary assigned to your local profile, I'd imagine these two words are contained in the default dictionary, which Mozilla recommends you NOT edit.