# How to remove words from the default spellchecker dictionary in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, spell-check, dictionary

I want to remove proper English words from the basic or enhanced spell checker in Google Chrome. For removal are the words hardwired in the default dictionaries, not added to a custom (user) dictionary.

What I've tried:

- I couldn't open chrome://settings/editDictionary in a recent version of Chrome. Brief inspection of chrome://about/ has not revealed alternatives.
- Locations like `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` and `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` relate to custom dictionaries.
- Editing anything in `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` would result in changes lost after Chrome autoupdate.

Are there other ways?

Related questions:

- [Google Chrome Dictionary Location](https://superuser.com/questions/280181/google-chrome-dictionary-location)
- [can I remove words from the firefox dictionary?](https://superuser.com/questions/1439553/can-i-remove-words-from-the-firefox-dictionary)
- [Firefox dictionary, deleting false entries](https://superuser.com/questions/40158/firefox-dictionary-deleting-false-entries)

Comment: Can you not just add your custom spelling to the user dictionary instead?

Comment: @Tetsujin The goal is to highlight certain properly typed words as improper. Alternating spelling of such words won't highlight their original spelling.